# How to make plugable factory work with lua?

Tags: c++, lua

class data is like this:

```
struct Base_data
{
public:
    Base_data(){
        protocolname = "Base";
    }
    string protocolname;
};

class HttpData : public Base_data
{
public:
    HttpData(){
        protocolname = "Http";
    }
};
```

class Professor:

```
class Base_Professor
{
public:
    void Process(Base_data &data)
    {
        std::map::const_iterator it = ListProfessor.find(data.protocolname);
        if(it == ListProfessor.end())
            cout second->Do(data);
    }

    virtual void Do(Base_data &data){}

    virtual std::string GetProfessorname(){
        return "Base";
    }

    ~Base_Professor(){
        std::map::const_iterator it;
        for(it = ListProfessor.begin(); it != ListProfessor.end(); ++it)
            delete it->second;
    }
    bool Register(Base_Professor *Professor){
        std::map::const_iterator it = ListProfessor.find(Professor->GetProfessorname());
        if(it != ListProfessor.end())
            return false;
        ListProfessor.insert(std::make_pair(Professor->GetProfessorname(), Professor));
    }
private:
    std::map ListProfessor;
};

class HttpProfessor : public Base_Professor
{
public:
    std::string GetProfessorname(){
        return "Http";
    }
    void Do(Base_data &data){
        std::cout
```

I can add new protocol by inheritant Base_Professor and register new class but I have no ideal how to do that in lua. Do you have any ideal how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua doesn't provide "classes" out-of-the-box. It has other features, somewhat different.

However you can simulate classes and inheritance functionality by using some of these functionalities (tables & metatables).

If you are not interested in knowing the technical details, you can use some already-built lua library.

I've myself created a library called "MiddleClass" that provides this functionality. You can find a manual in its [LÖVE wiki page](http://love2d.org/wiki/index.php?title=MiddleClass).

This library provides most of what you need, except for "public" and "private" functionalities (everything is "public"). You may find other libraries on the [lua users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming).